# #1# signature in macro definition

Tags: color, arguments, def

I'm reading the source code of `xcolor` and I'm a little bit confused about the following definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\testclr#1#{\@testclr{#1}}
\def\@testclr#1#2{{\fboxsep\z@\fbox{\colorbox#1{#2}{\phantom{XX}}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\testclr{magenta}
\testclr[rgb]{1,0,1}

\end{document}
```

What's the usage of the second `#` in `\def\testclr#1#{\@testclr{#1}}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\def\foo#1#{xxx [#1]}`

is primitive syntax that makes the first argument everything up to a (mandatory) `{`  so

`\foo hello world{}`

would produce `xxx [hello world]`

It's used here to save the higher level commands re-parsing any optional arguments as all optional arguments up to the `{` of the main argument are grabbed and passed on to the `\color` command.

This isn't really good latex style, but follows the precedent set by the `color` package where it saved a few bytes that needed saving at the time.

Comment: Thanks! It's a new tip about TeX which can be hardly found in general LaTeX  manuals.

Comment: @Stephen the latex rule would say: "don't do this", but the author  of the `color` package didn't follow rules. Shocking really.